# using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: xml, vb.net, parallel-processing

I'm trying to optimize a backup program that I created. The code is sloppy because it's my first program of this magnitude but hopefully you can look past that.

This program runs fine, but it seems to take longer than that necessary. So i am toying around with the Parallel.ForEach to help optimize the zipping process.

Right now, i have the program doing the zipping task in the following way

```vb
Dim Destin = JobNode.SelectNodes("Destination")

For Each item As System.Xml.XmlNode In Destin
    Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim format As String = "MMMddyyyy"
    Dim zpath As String = item.InnerText
    'replaces [date] in destination with actual Date 
    If time.DayOfWeek = 1 Then
        time = time.AddDays(-1)
        item.InnerText = Replace(item.InnerText, "[date]", time.ToString(format) & "_WE")
        zpath = item.InnerText
        zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1
        zip.Save(zpath)
    Else
        Dim time1 As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        item.InnerText = Replace(item.InnerText, "[date]", time1.ToString(format))
        zpath = item.InnerText
        zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1
        zip.Save(zpath)
    End If
Next
```

I have all of the source and destination locations saved into an xml file for reading. And this for each loop works just how i want it to. However, i'm having trouble converting this For each loop into a Parallel.ForEach loop.

Any help would be nice. Again, i'm still green when it comes to programming, so dumb it down for me.

And yes...i have looked around the internet for help but it either confuses me, doesn't work in my context, or i can't get it to work with my code.

Comment: Why do you think it takes longer than necessary? There is a good chance that your program is limited by the speed of the disk drive. If you're using Windows 7 (I don't know about Vista or Windows 8) then you can use Resource Monitor, which is available in the Performance tab of Task Manager (press ctrl+shift+esc), to see what is going on. On the Overview tab, have a look at the CPU and Disk charts on the right.

Comment: Well i suppose i dont know for sure if it's completely optimal. I'm just thinking that having each job being zipped on a seperate thread would HAVE to speed it up some. Zipping each job at the same time must save time..right?

Comment: Not necessarily: if the disk drive has to move the head back and forth to more places then you *might* make it slower by doing zipping files in parallel. Testing will reveal if that is the case. Remember that it has to move the head to read from the source file, then move it again to write to the destination file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Dim Destin = JobNode.SelectNodes("Destination").OfType(Of XmlNode)

    Dim format As String = "MMMddyyyy"
    Parallel.ForEach(Destin, 
      Sub(item)
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        Dim zpath As String = item.InnerText
        'replaces [date] in destination with actual Date 
        Dim timeString = If(time.DayOfWeek = 1, time.ToString(format) & "_WE", time.ToString(format))
        item.InnerText = Replace(item.InnerText, "[date]", timeString)
        zpath = item.InnerText
        zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1
        zip.Save(zpath)
       End Sub)
```

Comment: *AmbiguousMatchException was unhandled*   Overload resolution failed because no Public 'ForEach' can be called with these arguments:

    'Public Shared Function ForEach(Of TSource)(source As OrderablePartitioner(Of TSource), body As Action(Of TSource,ParallelLoopState,Long)) As System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopResult':

        Type argument inference fails for argument matching parameter 'source'.

        Type argument inference fails for argument matching parameter 'body'.

Comment: What is the type of JobNode? Does SelectNodes return an IEnumerable(Of T) or just IEnumerable? You may need to force the typing by using .OfType(Of x) when you are declaring Destin.

Comment: For Each JobNode in JobNodes....is where i call JobNode. And JobNodes is called by "Dim JobNodes as XmlNodeList = doc.getelementbytagname("Job")

Comment: IIRC, XmlNodeList only implements IEnumerable, not IEnumerable(Of XmlNode). Try the revision above.  Or better yet, try switching to LINQ to XML instead of the XmlDom.

Comment: would switching to LINQ require me changing the bulk of my code since it already reads and writes to XML? just curious, i've never worked with LINQ

Comment: Also, Jim, could you point me in the right direction at how to use the oftype(of x) ?

Comment: See if [this](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Using-Cast-Or-OfType-Methods) helps.

Comment: Yes, LINQ to XML is a different API. It is much easier to use than the XML Dom. It's even easier in VB with XML Literals. See [MSDN LINQ to XML Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx).